# rails testing fails to recognize path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, capybara

I am testing `test/models/user_test.rb` with

```
test "should validate login" do
    visit new_user_session
    fill_in "email", with: 'test@test.com'
    fill_in "password", with: 'testtest'
    click_button  "Sign in"
    assert_equal some_url, current_path
  end
```

When I run `ruby -Itest test/models/user_test.rb`, I get this error message

```
UserTest#test_should_validate_login:
NameError: undefined local variable or method `new_user_session' for #<UserTest:0x007fcbd8e98378>
    test/models/user_test.rb:22:in `block in <class:UserTest>'
```

If I change `new_user_session` to any other `path` that `rake routes` provide, I get the same message, namely `undefined local variable or method`path'`. Could someone help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're doing integration test but writing it in a model test.  The model test will not have routes and other niceties loaded for you to use.

Answer (score 0):

You need to append either `path` or `url` to the end of `new_user_session` to get the actual path:

```
  test "should validate login" do
    visit new_user_session_path
    fill_in "email", with: 'test@test.com'
    fill_in "password", with: 'testtest'
    click_button  "Sign in"
    assert_equal some_url, current_path
  end
```

See [the path and url helpers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#path-and-url-helpers) section of the Rails routing guide for more info.